# How to find if a Java String contains X or Y and contains Z

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm pretty sure regular expressions are the way to go, but my head hurts whenever I try to work out the specific regular expression.

What regular expression do I need to find if a Java String (contains the text "ERROR" or the text "WARNING") AND (contains the text "parsing"), where all matches are case-insensitive?

EDIT: I've presented a specific case, but my problem is more general. There may be other clauses, but they all involve matching a specific word, ignoring case. There may be 1, 2, 3 or more clauses.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're not 100% comfortable with regular expressions, don't try to use them for something like this.  Just do this instead:

```
string s = test_string.toLowerCase();
if (s.contains("parsing") && (s.contains("error") || s.contains("warning")) {
    ....
```

because when you come back to your code in six months time you'll understand it at a glance.

**Edit:** Here's a regular expression to do it:

```
(?i)(?=.*parsing)(.*(error|warning).*)
```

but it's rather inefficient.  For cases where you have an OR condition, a hybrid approach where you search for several simple regular expressions and combine the results programmatically with Java is usually best, both in terms of readability and efficiency.

Comment: Richie, you are right. However I've given a specific case to make the question easy to understand, but my problem is more general.

Comment: s.contains("error") or s.contains("warning") should actually be s.contains("error") || s.contains("warning"), isn't it?

Answer (score 7):

If you really want to use regular expressions, you can use the **positive lookahead** operator:

```
(?i)(?=.*?(?:ERROR|WARNING))(?=.*?parsing).*
```

Examples:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=.*?(?:ERROR|WARNING))(?=.*?parsing).*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE); // you can also use (?i) at the beginning
System.out.println(p.matcher("WARNING at line X doing parsing of Y").matches()); // true
System.out.println(p.matcher("An error at line X doing parsing of Y").matches()); // true
System.out.println(p.matcher("ERROR Hello parsing world").matches()); // true       
System.out.println(p.matcher("A problem at line X doing parsing of Y").matches()); // false
```

Comment: System.out.println("matches = " + Pattern.matches("(?=.*?(?:ERROR|WARNING))(?=.*?parsing)", "ERROR Hello parsing world"));
returns false... something wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 If((str.indexOf("WARNING") > -1 || str.indexOf("ERROR") > -1) && str.indexOf("parsin") > -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions are not needed here. Try this:

```
if((string1.toUpperCase().indexOf("ERROR",0) >= 0 ||  
  string1.toUpperCase().indexOf("WARNING",0) >= 0 ) &&
  string1.toUpperCase().indexOf("PARSING",0) >= 0 )
```

This also takes care of the case-insensitive criteria

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [this applet](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html) to experiment with reg. ex. The expression may look like this:

```
if (str.matches("(?i)^.*?(WARNING|ERROR).*?parsing.*$")) {
...
```

But as stated in above answers it's better to not use reg. ex. here.

Comment: System.out.println(Pattern.compile("(?i)^.*?(WARNING|ERROR).*?parsing.*$").matcher("parsing  ERROR Hello world").matches()); returns false...

Answer (score 0):

I think this regexp will do the trick (but there must be a better way to do it):

```
(.*(ERROR|WARNING).*parsing)|(.*parsing.*(ERROR|WARNING))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've a variable number of words that you want to match I would do something like that:

```
String mystring = "Text I want to match";
String[] matchings = {"warning", "error", "parse", ....}
int matches = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < matchings.length(); i++) {
  if (mystring.contains(matchings[i]) {
    matches++;
  }
}

if (matches == matchings.length) {
   System.out.println("All Matches found");
} else {
   System.out.println("Some word is not matching :(");
}
```

Note: I haven't compiled this code, so could contain typos.

Answer (score 0):

With multiple `.*` constucts the parser will invoke thousands of "back off and retry" trial matches.

Never use `.*` at the beginning or in the middle of a RegEx pattern.