# java checking string for inputs in a line of code

Tags: java, string

This is the code I have checking for q

```
while (!inputs.contains("q"))
```

How can I add multiple characters in this.. such as q and Q 
Or if I had like 5 different letters. q w e r t

Thanks!

Comment: @Nichowhat you want please specify more inputs and output

Comment: Why not use a regex? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437865/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) is the elegant way to do it (but you have to learn the [basics](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) of it beyond Java). I also love the regex tester in Intellij (probably eclipse also offers similar)

Something like this should help then `while(!inputs.matches("[qwertQWERT]"))`

Comment: Would you mind explaining why regex is "elegant" or the better way? compared to while (!input.matches("[qwertQWERT]")

Comment: `while(!inputs.matches("[qwertQWERT]"))` is using the regex. Regex are extremely powerful and in your case, instead of comparing each String separately, you can do it in one line of code. It is also possible to check for more complex conditions using regex such as whether your input starts with a digit etc.

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

```
while (!inputs.contains("q") ||  !inputs.contains("Q") || !inputs.contains("e"))
{
    // Code Here.....
}
```

and so on for the rest of the terminating characters

*Or* you can use regular expression (and the [`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method):

```
while (!input.matches("[qwertQWERT]")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!inputs.contains("q") || 
            !inputs.contains("Q") ||
            !inputs.contains("e") || !inputs.contains("w") || !inputs.contains("r") )

    {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking for single characters you could use a regex character class:

```
Pattern = Pattern.compile("[qwert]+");
while (!p.matcher(inputs).matches()) {
    ...
```

You will need to escape any characters that are special characters in regex.  And if you need to match more than one character, such as trying to match 'quit' this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use [StringUtils.containsAny](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsAny%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20char...%29)  from ApacheCommons and using `toUpperCase()` (or `toLowerCase()`) method you'll cover both cases:

```
String input = "Q";
String matcher = "qwert";
while (StringUtils.containsAny(input.toUpperCase(), matcher.toUpperCase().toCharArray()))   
{
    //something
}
```