# If statement for checking if a char array contains a user given letter in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement, char

I am trying to create a program in which a user enters a string (which is put into a char array) and then enters a letter and the program checks if the string contains that letter. Here is my code so far:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a word: ");
String input = keyboard.nextLine();
char[] word = input.toCharArray();

Scanner keyboard1 = new Scanner (System.in);
char letter = keyboard1.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
if (word contains letter) { //This is just used as an example of what I want it to do
    System.out.println("The word does contain the letter.");
} else {
    System.out.println("The word does not contain the letter.");
}
```

I realize that the condition in the if statement is not valid, I used it just as an example of what I want it to do.

So my question here is: What can I enter in the if statement condition for it to check if the user entered word contains the user entered letter?

Comment: Use [`input.contains(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find if a Java String contains X or Y and contains Z](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437865/how-to-find-if-a-java-string-contains-x-or-y-and-contains-z)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to convert your first input to a `char[]`, just leave it as a string and use the `contains()`

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a word: ");
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Please enter a letter to search in the word: ");
    Scanner keyboard1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    char letter = keyboard1.nextLine().charAt(0);

    // Using toLowerCase() to ignore capital vs lowercase letters.
    // Locale may need to be considered.
    if (input.toLowerCase().contains(String.valueOf(letter).toLowerCase())) { 
        System.out.println("The word does contain the letter " + letter + ".");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The word does not contain the letter " + letter + ".");
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want it on one line:

```
if (new String(word).indexOf(letter) != -1)
```

Otherwise use a loop:

```
boolean found = false;
for (char c : word) {
    if (c == letter) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (found)
```